# Finding the diagonal side of an isosceles triangle

Tags: geometry

Using geometry I would like to find the diagonal length of an isosceles  triangle. I only know that the base of the triangle is 36” long, The lower left angle is 45° and the lower right angle is 90° I don’t know the height. Using geometry how would I find the length of the diagonal leg of the triangle.

Comment: What exactly do you mean be "diagonal" and "diagonal leg".  Note your triangle is a right triangle *and* an isoceles triangle.  So use the Pythagorian theorem......

Answer (score 0):

From the information you've given, your triangle is right-angled and isosceles like this:
[image]
Your diagonal leg is $c$, and you know that the base is $a=36$ (disregarding units). Since the triangle is isosceles, we have that the height is $b=36$ as well. By the Pythagorean theorem, we have
$$
c^2=a^2+b^2\implies c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \implies c=\sqrt{2(36^2)}=36\sqrt2.
$$
The diagonal leg is $36\sqrt2 \approx 50.91$ inches.

Answer (score 0):

My assumption is that the "base" is the horizontal. Since one of the angles next to the base is $90^\circ$, then the "height" (vertical) will be the same as the "base" $a=b=36$. The reason is that the triangle is isosceles. Then use Pythagoras' to get the hypotenuse (which will look diagonal in this picture):
$$c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}=36\sqrt 2$$